# What are the visa requirements for US citizen travelling to Italy with a layover in Istanbul?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, turkey

I am traveling from Chicago O'Hare on Turkish Airlines to Istanbul Turkey.
I have a layover in Istanbul for 5 hrs, then board Turkish Airlines and travel to Rome Italy.

I have a current US Passport. Is there a need for a visa in either Turkey or Italy?

Comment: Are you planning on leaving the airport?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/i-am-american-with-passport-having-layover-in-istanbul-for-20-hours-do-i-need-v

Comment: Your ability to enter Italy without a visa depends on the purpose and duration of your trip.

Answer (score 4):

In order to enter Turkey for touristic purposes as a US citizen, [you need a visa which can be bought upon arrival](http://turkey.usembassy.gov/visa_requirements.html). It costs $20:

> American citizens traveling to Turkey on U.S. passports must obtain a visa. Currently, holders of all types of passports can purchase a 90-day sticker visa at the port of entry for $20 cash if they are traveling to Turkey as tourists.

As long as you do not exit the international terminal at the airport, you do not need a visa.

[To travel to Italy, you do not need a visa.](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/italy.html) You can stay upto 90 days in Italy (Entire Schengen Zone) for touristic purposes as a US citizen.

> U.S. citizens may enter Italy for up to 90 days for tourist or business purposes without a visa.   All non-residents are required to complete a declaration of presence (dichiarazione di presenza).

For future references: This site is not Google. By typing "US citizen [country] visa" on google you can get the same results I got within seconds. Please do your research beforehand in the future.

Comment: @MertKarakaya It's not a matter of professionalism. :) Rather, links are often broken/changed so we try to include the text they cover in the posts. This way the content isn't lost.

Comment: As the quoted material implies, but the body of the answer does not state, a US citizen may travel to Italy without a visa *only for certain purposes* and for a limited period.

Comment: @phoog I have now specificly stated "touristic purposes" and "US citizen". That's what you meant, correct?